# Could not start trace on Android Emulator with GAPID

Tags: java, android, adb, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to debug an OpenGL ES application on an Android Emulator (x86). I'm working on a Mac OSX. I have correctly installed the app on an emulator, that run correctly, even it does not display what I need. I found that exist the `Graphics API Debugger` by Google. As it was written in the [documentation](https://gapid.dev/about/), before starting with GAPI, I close Android Studio. Every time I try to trace the application I receive the following error:

```
Could not start trace
   Cause: loadGAPII
   Cause: Exception raised calling: public static void java.lang.System.load(java.lang.String)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
```

Some questions: it is possible to run GAPI on Android emulator x86? If the answer is yes, what should I do to allow it to work? Thank you in advance.

[image: GAPI Error]

Answer (score 1):

Just to share. In the [requirements page](https://gapid.dev/requirements/) is clearly written `Tracing on Android emulators is not supported`.